# llamando a swi-prolog desde php

Tags: php

Tengo un problema para conectar `php` con `swi-prolog`:

Trabajo con la plataforma `xampp`.

Estoy usando dos programas:

a. Uno en prolog, de nombre ejemplo.pl, cuyo código es el siguiente:

```
test:- write('hola mundo').
```

b. y otro en php, index.php:

```
<?php  
  if(!file_exists("ejemplo.pl")) die("No se puede localizar el archivo ejemplo.pl, el directorio actual es: ".__DIR__);
  $output = `swipl -s ejemplo.pl -g "test." -t halt.`;
  var_dump($output);
?>
```

Ambos programas están en la carpeta `C:\xampp\htdocs\experto`
también copié en esta carpeta "experto" el `swipl`.
Cuando hago una prueba preliminar desde el `Windows PowerShell` con la siguiente sentencia:

```
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\experto> -s ejemplo.pl -g "test." -t halt.
```

responde:

```
hola mundo
```

sin embargo cuando llamo al `index.php`:

```
http://localhost/experto/
```

me responde:

```
NULL
```

Además quiero decir que cuando me conecto a través de la consola `cmd` de `windows`, también falla:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\experto>swipl -s ejemplo.pl -g "test." -t halt.
```

"`swipl`" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.

No sé porqué no logro llamar exitosamente a `SWI-Prolog` desde `PHP`.

Agradecido de antemano,
Jorge Fuentes

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Te falto agregar como lo haces desde php.

Comment: Gracias por tus consejos, es la primera pregunta que elaboro. Uso php en el archivo index.php

Comment: mhplur Lamento las faltas de ortografía. y la mezcla de texto con código.

Comment: Jorge no es necesario que te disculpes. Estamos para ayudarnos entre todos. Por favor, revisa los links que te pase en mi comentario para que entiendas como funcionamos.

Comment: en eso estoy. aprendiendo el funcionamiento de este inteligente sitio. gracias gbianchi

Comment: hola tengo un problema similar, me sale null la conexión, alguién que me pueda ayudar.